# Powershell folder archiving

Tags: powershell, archive, 7zip

I have a powershell script that simply uses the Get-ChildItem command to search through a directory for a folder matching a keyword.  When found I need it to zip it and leave it right in that same directory.

Here's what I've tried by piping the command into both 7zip and the native compress:

```
    set-alias zip "$env:ProgramFiles\7-Zip\7z.exe"
    Get-ChildItem $path "keyword" -Recurse -Directory | zip a
AND
    Get-ChildItem $path"keyword" -Recurse -Directory | compress-archive
```

Both times it always asks for a source and destination which is hard to define since I'm having it search through a drive with many sub-folders.  I though using the pipe would imply the source as well.

Any ideas?  Thanks!

EDIT:

I suppose I could set the Get-ChildItem to a variable and use that as the "source" and have the destination be a generic location for them all but I'd have to name them differently, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
$path = "INSERT SOURCE ROOT"

foreach ($directory in Get-ChildItem $path -Recurse -Directory -Filter "keyword"| Select-Object FullName | foreach { $_.FullName}) {
    $destination = Split-Path -Path $directory -Parent

    Compress-Archive -Path $directory -DestinationPath $destination

}
```

This is looking inside the path for anything matching the "keyword", going up 1 level, and then zipping the found file.

Comment: Thank you!!  Solved my problem.  Only change I made was the destination path to $directory also, that way it put the zip in the sub-folder itself

Answer (score 0):

With `temp` and `temp2` directories under `C:\` this is working for me (note that the directories must have content):

`Get-ChildItem "C:\" "temp*" -directory | compress-archive -DestinationPath "C:\tempzip.zip"`

It zips all directories found to `C:\tempzip.zip`.

I believe what you actually want is:

```
$dirs = Get-ChildItem "C:\" "temp*" -directory
foreach ($dir in $dirs){
    compress-archive $dir.fullname -DestinationPath "$($dir.fullname).zip"
}
```

Note that I omitted `-recurse` for my testing.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
get-childitem -path "The Source Path" -recurse | where {$_.Name -match "Keyword"} | foreach {
  $parent = Split-Path -Path $_ -Parent
  Compress-Archive -Path $_ -DestinationPath $parent
}
```